# Moment.js: Date.now() javaScript analogue

Tags: javascript, unix-timestamp, utc, momentjs

Is there any simple way to get a number of milliseconds elapsed since `1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC` simular the `Date.now()` javaScript function?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `valueOf` method on a moment object:

For local time:

```
moment().valueOf();
```

For UTC:

```
moment().utc().valueOf();
```

Comment: These two return same value, so no need the second IMHO.

Comment: Depends on where you reside and if your browser / system represents the actual timezone you are in ;) Then those two may differ...

Answer (score 29):

To get current date you may use the following line in your js file:

```
var currentDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

It will show the date of the given format 19-Mar-2015

[Click here to visit moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for answering it here for us waywards.

Answer (score 13):

Date.now() is the simplest. Otherwise the following using simple javascript can be used:-

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Using moment.js

```
moment().valueOf()
```

can be used.

```
moment("...").valueOf()
```

can be used to get the time elapsed since a particular date.